# C++: How to stack for loop iterations properly

Tags: c++

I am working in the textbook, "Principles and Practice Using C++, second edition." I am in the section about vectors, and I'm having trouble stacking my for loops to get the output I'm looking for.

```
// simple dictionary: list of sorted words
int main() {
  vector < string > words;
  for (string temp; cin >> temp;) // read whitespace-separated words
    words.push_back(temp); // put into vector

  cout << "\nNumber of words: " << words.size() << '\n';

  sort(words); // sort the words

  vector < string > disliked = {"Test", "Set"};

  for (int i = 0; i < words.size(); ++i)
    if (i == 0 || words[i - 1] != words[i]) {
      for (int b = 0; b < disliked.size(); ++b)
        if (i == 0 || words[i] == disliked[b])
          cout << words[i] << "\n";
    }

}
```

This is meant to skip printing repeated words, and treat the disliked vector as filtered words and exclude them as well. I am positive I'm doing something weird with my for loop, and I've rearranged it in several ways but can't seem to figure out how to tweak it just right. I have had it working with just skipping repeated words, and I've been able to make it skip a single string but not a vector with strings.

This is the output it give me if I type in

yes yes Test no Set Set Test lol if if this works

Number of words: 12
Set
Set
Test
Program ended with exit code: 0

Comment: This line `if (i == 0 || words[i] == disliked[b])` ensures you will ONLY output the first word or words that DO appear in the disliked vector. That's not what you meant is it?

Comment: @RobP I was messing with both != and == so that's what I had last.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a minimal change in your loop :

```
  bool ok;
  for (int i = 0; i < words.size(); ++i)
    if (i == 0 || words[i - 1] != words[i]) {
        ok = true;
        for (int b = 0; b < disliked.size(); ++b)
            if (words[i] == disliked[b]) ok = false;
        if (ok) cout << words[i] << "\n";
    }
```

The output is then (I commented out the sort ...)

```
yes
no
lol
if
this
works
```

Comment: Thank you, this works and I see why. Took me a moment to realize you meant 'bool', not book.

Comment: @BleuGamer : Oups ! It is the only line I re-typed because it was higher in the source ... Fixed ;-)

Comment: Using bool actually opened up other ideas I didn't think about, so thanks!

Answer (score 0):

one of many approaches:

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>
#include <set>
#include <iterator>

using namespace std;

int main() {

    // simulates reading from standard input
    const vector<string> input_words = { "the", "quick", "brown", "mega", "fox", "jumps", "over", "the", "lazy", "brown", "dog" };

    // the set of disliked words
    const set<string> disliked_words = { "the", "mega" };

    // all containers can be constructed with any compatible iterator range
    // sets are automatically sorted and de-duplicated        
    set<string> filtered_words { input_words.begin(), input_words.end() };

    // c++11 range-based for loop. If you're using c++03 use the equivalent
    // for(it = disliked_words.begin() ; it != disliked_words.end() ; ++it) ...
    for (const auto& not_liked : disliked_words) {
        filtered_words.erase(not_liked);
    }

    // copy each filtered word to standard out with a newline separator        
    copy(filtered_words.begin(), filtered_words.end(), ostream_iterator<string>(cout, "\n"));

    return 0;
}
```

If you want to maintain the relative order of the input words, you'll want a stable filter function:

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>
#include <set>
#include <iterator>

using namespace std;

// make a copy of the vector, removing duplicates and disliked words.
// relative order of remaining words is maintained.
vector<string> deduplicated_and_filtered_copy_stable(const vector<string>& input, const set<string>& disliked)
{
    vector<string> result;
    set<string> seen;

    copy_if(begin(input),
            end(input),
            back_inserter(result),
            [&](const string& s) {
                return (!disliked.count(s)) && seen.insert(s).second;
            });

    return result;
}

int main() {

    const vector<string> input_words = { "the", "quick", "brown", "mega", "fox", "jumps", "over", "the", "lazy", "brown", "dog" };
    const set<string> disliked_words = { "the", "mega" };

    auto filtered_words = deduplicated_and_filtered_copy_stable(input_words, disliked_words);

    copy(filtered_words.begin(), filtered_words.end(), ostream_iterator<string>(cout, "\n"));

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I like this... I'll learn more standard and accepted forms later, but for now I'm just learning the fundamentals.

Comment: good on you mate. Once you've learned the fundamentals the most valuable thing you can do is to learn the <algorithm> library. Almost every operation you will ever do with data already has a faultless and highly optimised implementation there, or can be written by combining the standard algorithms.

Comment: Thank you for the tip! I will keep this in mind. @Richard Hodges